# Assigning a created object to a selected object

Tags: c++, object, fibonacci

I have made a class of large numbers. In my program, a menu asks a user what they want to do with any of three objects of that class that has been created for them. One of their options is Fibonacci, at which point they must also enter a number and choose one of the objects.

The input number is the number in the Fibonacci sequence, and it is put into the Large Number class. I have gotten everything to work so far, and it calculated up to the 9999th Fibonacci number, but here is my problem:

In the Large Number class is the fibonacci method which creates a Large Number object. I now want to make the selected object be that created object.

Below is my fibonacci method. I have added some comments to explain what is going on.

```
    void fibonacci(int n){
        Large *One = new Large(), *Two = new Large();
        One->makeOne(); // initializes the object
        Two->makeOne(); // same here
        Two->first->setnum(1); // sets "Large Number" Two to 1 (One is already 0)

        int current = 0; // counter
        while (current != n){
            Large *Temp = new Large();
            Temp->add(One,Two); // sums One and Two into a temporary Large Number
            One = Two;
            Two = Temp;
            current++;
        }

        this = One; // <-- here is my question
    }
```

You may trust that the correct number is created once the while loop finishes. But now I want the chosen object to become the created number ("One").

The method is called in something like the following matter:

```
Large A = Large();
A.fibonacci(n);
```

How would I make `A` (which would be `this` ) equal to `One`.

`this = One;` does not work. `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

**Q: What is the correct way of assigning the created object to the selected object?**

Comment: You cannot re-assign a this pointer. You need to structure your code different. Store the object in a variable, rather than trying to change "this"

Comment: How about `*this = *One`? It should call the copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is change the `this` pointer, that is, you're trying to change where `this` points, which is illegal in C++. You *can*, however, change the value(s) of the field(s) of the object that `this` points to. Something like:

```
this->a = One->a;
```

...assuming you have some field `a` in your class. You can then do this for each field in your class. In the end, the object pointed to by `this` will be a copy of the object pointed to by `One`.

A more concise approach would be:

```
*this = *One;
```

...which, semantically, means "set the thing that `this` points to the same value as the thing that `One` points to. By default (unless you've overridden the copy operator to do something else) for class types this means that each field in `One` will be copied to the corresponding field in `this`.

Also, as an aside, you're leaking lots of object allocations in this code. (You need to `delete` objects you've `new`'ed when you're done with them.)